# parbox doesn't span text over two columns

Tags: luatex, two-column, parbox

In the document I'm writing I need to use a `parbox` with long text. The problem is that the text inside the `parbox` doesn't span over two columns. How to make the text inside continue to the next column and to the next page? I'm compiling it with `LuaLaTeX`.

Here's a MWE of my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%   \lipsum[1-7]
    \parbox[t]{\columnwidth}{\lipsum[1-7]}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the main reason to put something in a parbox is to prevent column and page breaking, so simply not using `\parbox` would be the normal answer here. Why do you want a \parbox` ?

Comment: If you need to use locally both columns, you have the `strip` environment from `cuted`.